# How to code a subscript character in an equation that uses textrm

Tags: equations, subscripts, underscore

I'm a novice with LaTeX.

I'm aiming for this subscript character at the beginning of an equation (essentially Z<sub>i</sub>):

[image: Capital Z followed by subscript i]

I've started with a source file that uses an underscore to get the subscript:

```
$$\begin{equation}\textrm{Z_i}
```

However this is being rendered as an underscore character: Z_i

A suggestion to fix this is separating the subscript character into a new textrm, preceded by the underscore:

```
$$\begin{equation}\textrm{Z}_{\textrm{i}}
```

I'm trying to pinpoint whether and exactly how the initial code is wrong, in order to prevent recurrences in future documents. I also don't want to flag code as wrong if actually there are legitimate similar cases.

Questions:

- Why exactly is the underscore being displayed instead of the subscript? Is that just always the case for underscores within textrm?
- Is the suggestion correct, or would you do it differently for any reason?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I'm afraid `$$\begin{equation}` has absolutely no chance of compiling properly. You must be getting a ton of error messages; do *not* ignore them. And who tought you to write `$$\begin{equation}`?

Comment: as Mico says the `$$` will already give errors.  also `\textrm` enters text mode so math constructs such as `_` will not work.  Use  `\mathrm{Z}_{\mathrm{i}}`

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle! You distinguish between text and maths, but in your code example the two characters are separated into two \mathrm tags. Would \mathrm{Z_i} have the same problem as \textrm{Z_i} ? My focus for this is not on the $$ but thank you for that too.

Comment: Your focus _should_ be the `$$` as after `$$\begin{equation}` you get an error and after any error the pdf output is not intended to be usable.  You could use `\mathrm{Z_i}` but the form I showed is better.